# i need my own exception class and it should have both run time and compile time exceptions in java

Tags: java

i need my own exception class and it should have both run time and checked exceptions in java. Is it possible to write a class please tell me.

Comment: `compile time exceptions` - there's no such thing. Perhaps you meant checked exceptions

Comment: Are you asking about the super class Exception ?

Comment: no i need child class

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is you're asking.  Are you asking how to create an exception class that is checked, or a runtime exception, or one that combines the two together?

Comment: one that combines the two together @Makoto

Comment: Are you aware of the different types of exceptions and what their role actually is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have them both in a single class. You either extend `Exception` for having a checked exception or `RuntimeException` for an unchecked one.

Comment: what i need to have them both.

Comment: You can't do that. What you can do is make two exception classes: a checked and an unchecked one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the answer:  **what you are asking for is not possible.**

There is no way to combine the properties of both a runtime exception and a checked exception into a *single* exception class.

For why, we can reference the language specification.

First, [the different kinds of exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1):  `Exception`, `RuntimeException`, and `Error`.

All three share the same property in that they extend `Throwable`, but that's about where the similarities start fading.

- An `Exception` and its children are considered to be *checked*; if a method declares an exception of this type, then the **compiler** [enforces a check](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2) on all methods that use it; if any check fails, a compile-time error results.

  The idea here is that the exceptional behavior is reasonable enough to recover from, and the general operation of the program *should* continue in spite of the error.  A simple example is [`FileNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html), which means that the method that invoked this particular exception could not find a file.  Depending on the operations being done, that is an error that one *may* be able to recover from.
- A `RuntimeException` and its children are considred to be *unchecked*.  Normally a method doesn't declare this to be thrown, and if it did, the compiler would exempt it from its check.

  These exceptions indicate behavior that is the result of an error in programming, and in general *shouldn't* be caught.  The most common example is `NullPointerException`; you're trying to dereference an instance that doesn't exist.  The program has no reasonable recourse to continue running, since an assumption was made about the flow of the program which turned out to be wrong.
- An `Error` and its children are considered to be *unchecked* as well, but are special:  you are **not** expected to be able to recover from these sorts of exceptions.

  An example would be an `OutOfMemoryError`.  You're *out of memory*; there's not much that you can recover from.

---

All that said above, checked and unchecked exceptions are mutually exclusive types which each serve a different and **distinct** purpose.

You must be **explicit** about the kind of exception you're trying to catch.

- If the exception you need to produce is one in which you can reasonably recover from, then use a *checked* exception.
- If the exception you need to produce is one in which you cannot reasonably recover from, then use an *unchecked* (runtime) exception.

You **cannot combine the two.**